# Python function composition

Tags: python, function-composition

I've tried to implement function composition with nice syntax and here is what I've got:

```
from functools import partial

class _compfunc(partial):
    def __lshift__(self, y):
        f = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.func(y(*args, **kwargs)) 
        return _compfunc(f)

    def __rshift__(self, y):
        f = lambda *args, **kwargs: y(self.func(*args, **kwargs)) 
        return _compfunc(f)

def composable(f):
    return _compfunc(f)

@composable    
def f1(x):
    return x * 2

@composable
def f2(x):
    return  x + 3

@composable
def f3(x):
    return (-1) * x

print f1(2) #4
print f2(2) #5
print (f1 << f2 << f1)(2) #14
print (f3 >> f2)(2) #1
print (f2 >> f3)(2) #-5
```

It works fine with integers, but fails on lists/tuples:

```
@composable
def f4(a):
    a.append(0)

print f4([1, 2]) #None
```

Where is a mistake?

Comment: I assume that by "crushes" you mean "crashes"? And by "crashes" I assume you mean "throws an exception"? Also, if I run the exact code you posted, it works just fine.

Comment: I fail to see how `f4()` isn't working as designed. Perhaps you have mistaken expectations.

Comment: Thanks, Ignacio. I've made a really stupid mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`append` does in-place addition, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said (well, implied) -- so, while you could fix that by just adding a `return` to your function, it would have the side-effect of changing the argument it was passed, too:

```
@composable
def f4(a):
    a.append(0)
    return a
```

It would be best to use the following even more concise code which also creates and returns a new object:

```
@composable
def f4(a):
  return a + [0]
```